# Why is there a "Philosophy" tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

I just noticed that there are 7 questions tagged with [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy). Is it just me, or is this a terribly ambiguous tag? Should this tag not be removed, so that all questions will have at least a moderately specific [ethics](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) or [philosophy-of-science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy-of-science) tag or something of the sort? [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) just seems completely useless, given that this site is only for philosophy to begin with. Removing it could save a lot of pain in the long run, since it will get people  (including new users) used to the idea of more specific tags, and save a lot of re-tagging.

What do you think?

Comment: Wow, certainly agreed. It's a useless tag.

Comment: Oh... good catch. That's sort of funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag has been removed and will not be allowed on any new questions.